# How to access OWIN Context from IFileSystem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin

In my OWIN WebApi app I provide files through an `IFileSystem` instance.

Is there a possibility to access the OWIN context? I'd like to access the request to read the host and the cookie values.

If not directly accessible, is it possible to save the context into a service in an earlier step in the OWIN pipeline so I can fetch it from there?

Comment: Why can't you use `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()`?

Comment: Because `HttpContext.Current` is null :-(

Comment: use `Request.GetOwinContext()`